# Append all logs to /var/log

Tags: linux, append, logging

Application scenario:

I have the (normal/permanent) /var/log mounted on an encrypted partition (/dev/LVG/log). /dev/LVG/log is not accessible at boot time, it needs to be manually activated later by su from ssh.

A RAM drive (using tmpfs) is mounted to /var/log at init time (in rc.local).

Once /dev/LVG/log is activated, I need a good way of appending everything in the tmpfs to /dev/LVG/log, before mounting it as /var/log.

Any recommendations on what would be a good way of doing so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it doesn't seem a good idea, to me: it looks like you're going to loose many logs. If something goes wrong, you'll never know why.

Comment: This _is_ programming related. Apps must deal with the host OS, apps have design guidelines, often the two conflict.

Comment: @Tim: who said it isn't?

Comment: @giorgian: There are currently two votes to close this question as not programming related / belongs on serverfault.com respectively.

Comment: @Tim: ok, thanks. @everybody else: don't close this question.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is block until you somehow verify that /var/log is mounted on an encrypted VG, or queue log entries until that happened if your app must start on boot, which could get kind of expensive. You can't be responsible for every other app on the system and I can't see any reason to encrypt boot logs.

Then again, if you *know* the machine has heap to spare, a log queue that flushed once some event said it was OK to write to disk would seem sensible. That's no more expensive than the history that most shells keep, as long as you take care to avoid floods of events that could fill up the queue.

This does not account for possible log loss, but could with a little imagination.

Answer (score 0):

There is a risk you could lose logging.  You might want to try and write your logs to a file in /tmp which is tmpfs and thus in memory.  You could then append the content to your encrypted volume and then remove the file in tmp.  Of course if your machine failed to boot and went down again tmp would be erased and so you'd lose a good way of working out why.